# Enzyme does not reflect state update

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-redux, enzyme

I am writing tests for a React component connected to a Redux store. What I want to test is that when I dispatch `reset` on the store, the component state gets back to default.

The idea is as follows: when RESET dispatched, the component receives the truthy reset property and in `componentWillReceiveProps` sets the component state to default. It works, but it does not pass the test. If I hook up the debugger and run the test, I can see that it goes through setting state in `componentWillReceiveProps` but then when I expect the `timeLeft` state to be 10000, it is still 1111 as set above. What am I missing? This might be not a perfect way to test but I am sort of new to React/Redux component testing and would be happy to hear best practices to improve the way I test it.

Reducer:

```
const resetReducer = (state, action) => (action.type === 'RESET');
```

Component:

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(next) {
    if (next.reset) {
      this.setState({
        timeLeft: 10000,
      });
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    reset: state.reset
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Timer);
```

Test:

```
it('Reset', () => {
    // use mount because I need componentWillReceiveProps to run
    const wrapper = mount(<Timer/>);

    wrapper.setState({
      timeLeft: 1111
    });

    store.dispatch({ type: 'RESET' });
    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.state('timeLeft)).toBe(10000);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to test the Redux functionality. You should isolate and just test if your React code works right.

change this line

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
```

to

```
export class Timer extends React.Component {
```

In your test file

```
import { Timer } from './file-location';
```

And you can test your component behaviour like this

```
it('Reset', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Timer reset={false}/>);

  wrapper.setState({
    timeLeft: 1111
  });
  wrapper.update();
  expect(wrapper.state().timeLeft).toBe(1111);

  wrapper.setProps({ reset: true});
  wrapper.update();
  expect(wrapper.state().timeLeft).toBe(10000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Enzyme won't allow you to make this kind of test when you're writing Unit Tests, because with `mount` and `shallow` you're isolating the component. Isn't a `connected` component anymore.

That's why even when you call to the 'RESET' action, the component don't receive the change.

What you can do to be able to test if the component is updating when the props are correct, you can just update the props like this:

```
 wrapper.setProps({ timeLeft: 10000});
```

With this, you can force the component to receive the props and check is the behavior is what you expect it.

```
it('Reset', () => {
    // use mount because I need componentWillReceiveProps to run
    const wrapper = mount(<Timer/>);

    wrapper.setState({
      timeLeft: 1111
    });

    wrapper.setProps({ timeLeft: 10000});
    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.state('timeLeft)).toBe(10000);
});
```

And then, to test the Reducer you can follow the official documentation: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md

Remember the idea of the Unit Test is to isolate and split everything into small parts of the code.
If you wanna test the integration between components, try with Automation Tets.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks. One thing, in this case, it makes more sense to pass reset rather than timeLeft to props and see if this changes state as expected. Then, I'll want to know just whether the reducer sets reset properly when I dispatch the RESET action and whether the reset button dispatches the actions but these are not related to this component.